# gstreamer, rendering rtspsrc in winforms (and WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, gstreamer

The application I am attempting to write takes a video stream based on a video server on my network and displays it in a winforms window (and later I hope to host the same type of control in WPF). I am using gstreamer-sharp as my app is based on c#.net.

I successfully got videotestsrc working based on the code example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916330/display-gstreamer-sharp-video-stream-in-winforms) and was able to create several instances of the testvideosrc displaying as required in the window using VideoOverlayAdapter and a set of winForms panels.

When I moved onto getting rtspsrc doing the same I naturally ran into some hurdles which I am trying to get past, the code for my class is below.

Instead of linking the rtspsrc in the initialising code I believe I need to link the new pad of the rtspsrc to the next element (in this case rtph264depay) and this is where I have ran into trouble.

The PadAdded event seems to be fired sometimes within seconds of starting the program and sometimes not at all? The server works fine with the gstreamer-sharp version of the basic tutorials (part 1) and with good latency (easily less than 300ms, but I need to do a glass to glass test once I have my app working).

Also once the PadAdded event finally fires I get a NOFORMAT status when attempting to link the new pad to the rtph264depay sink pad.

I also notice that I don't seem to be getting the prepare window handle bus sync message where I would set the video overlay adapter like in the gstVideoOverlay example (so I wouldnt get output to the window handle I need even if the pad linking was successful).

Ive not been able to find this particular problem (rtspsrc pad not linking to rtph264depay sink pad) as similar questions seem to be regarding linking other elements together.

The initial linking of the remaining elements in the initialise code are successful according to the debug messages.

The end goal would be to get the frames into OpenCV/Emgu and do some analysis and basic overlay work.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Many thanks!

```
/// <summary>
/// class to create a gstreamer pipeline based on an rtsp stream at the provided URL
/// </summary>
class gstPipeline2
{
    // elements for the pipeline
    private Element rtspsrc, rtph264depay, decoder, videoConv, videoSink;
    private System.Threading.Thread mainGLibThread;
    private GLib.MainLoop mainLoop;

    // the window handle (passed in)
    private IntPtr windowHandle;
    // our pipeline
    private Pipeline currentPipeline = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new gstreamer pipeline rendering the stream at URL into the provided window handle 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="WindowHandle">The handle of the window to render to </param>
    /// <param name="Url">The url of the video stream</param>
    public gstPipeline2(IntPtr WindowHandle, string Url)
    {
        windowHandle = WindowHandle;    // get the handle and save it locally

        // initialise the gstreamer library and associated threads (for diagnostics)
        Gst.Application.Init(); 
        mainLoop = new GLib.MainLoop();
        mainGLibThread = new System.Threading.Thread(mainLoop.Run);
        mainGLibThread.Start();

        // create each element now for the pipeline
        // starting with the rtspsrc
        rtspsrc = ElementFactory.Make("rtspsrc", "udpsrc0");  // create an rtsp source
        rtspsrc["location"] = Url;   // and set its location (the source of the data)
        rtph264depay = ElementFactory.Make("rtph264depay", "rtph264depay0");    
        decoder = ElementFactory.Make("avdec_h264", "decoder0");    
        videoConv = ElementFactory.Make("videoconvert", "videoconvert0");   
        videoSink = ElementFactory.Make("autovideosink", "sink0");  // and finally the sink to render the video (redirected to the required window handle below in Bus_SyncMessage() ) 

        // create our pipeline which links all the elements together into a valid data flow
        currentPipeline = new Pipeline("pipeline");
        currentPipeline.Add(rtspsrc, rtph264depay, decoder, videoConv, videoSink); // add the required elements into it

        // link the various bits together in the correct order
        if(!rtph264depay.Link(decoder))
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("rtph264depay could not be linked to decoder (bad)");
        else
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("rtph264depay linked to decoder (good)");

        if (!decoder.Link(videoConv))
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("decoder could not be linked to videoconvert (bad)");
        else
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("decoder linked to videoconvert (good)");

        if (!videoConv.Link(videoSink))
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("videoconvert could not be linked to autovideosink (bad)");
        else
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("videoconvert linked to autovideosink (good)");

        rtspsrc.PadAdded += Rtspsrc_PadAdded; // subscribe to the PadAdded event so we can link new pads (sources of data?) to the depayloader when they arrive

        // subscribe to the messaging system of the bus and pipeline so we can minotr status as we go
        Bus bus = currentPipeline.Bus;
        bus.AddSignalWatch();
        bus.Message += Bus_Message;

        bus.EnableSyncMessageEmission();
        bus.SyncMessage += Bus_SyncMessage;

        // finally set the state of the pipeline running so we can get data
        var setStateReturn = currentPipeline.SetState(State.Null);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SetStateNULL returned: " + setStateReturn.ToString());
        setStateReturn = currentPipeline.SetState(State.Ready);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SetStateReady returned: " + setStateReturn.ToString());
        setStateReturn = currentPipeline.SetState(State.Playing);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SetStatePlaying returned: " + setStateReturn.ToString());
    }

    private void Rtspsrc_PadAdded(object o, PadAddedArgs args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Rtspsrc_PadAdded: called with new pad named: " + args.NewPad.Name);

        // a pad has been added to the source so we need to link it to the rest of the pipeline to ultimately display it onscreen
        Pad sinkPad = rtph264depay.GetStaticPad("sink");   // get the sink pad for the one we have recieved  so we can link to the depayloader element
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Rtspsrc_PadAdded: rtps264depay sink pad returned: " + sinkPad.Name);

        PadLinkReturn ret = args.NewPad.Link(sinkPad);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Rtspsrc_PadAdded: link attempt returned: " + ret.ToString());
    }

    public void killProcess()
    {
        mainLoop.Quit();
    }

    private void Bus_SyncMessage(object o, SyncMessageArgs args)
    {
        if (Gst.Video.Global.IsVideoOverlayPrepareWindowHandleMessage(args.Message))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bus_SyncMessage: Message prepare window handle received by: " + args.Message.Src.Name + " " + args.Message.Src.GetType().ToString());

            if (args.Message.Src != null)
            {
                // these checks were in the testvideosrc example and failed, args.Message.Src is always Gst.Element???
                if (args.Message.Src is Gst.Video.VideoSink)
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bus_SyncMessage: source is VideoSink");
                else
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bus_SyncMessage: source is NOT VideoSink");

                if (args.Message.Src is Gst.Bin)
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bus_SyncMessage: source is Bin");
                else
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bus_SyncMessage: source is NOT Bin");

                try
                {
                    args.Message.Src["force-aspect-ratio"] = true;
                }
                catch (PropertyNotFoundException) { }

                try
                {
                    Gst.Video.VideoOverlayAdapter adapter = new VideoOverlayAdapter(args.Message.Src.Handle);
                    adapter.WindowHandle = windowHandle;
                    adapter.HandleEvents(true);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bus_SyncMessage: Handle passed to adapter: " + windowHandle.ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bus_SyncMessage: Exception Thrown (overlay stage): " + ex.Message); }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string info;
            IntPtr prt;
            args.Message.ParseInfo(out prt, out info);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bus_SyncMessage: " + args.Message.Type.ToString() + " - " + info);
        }
    }

    private void Bus_Message(object o, MessageArgs args)
    {
        var msg = args.Message;
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("HandleMessage received msg of type: {0}", msg.Type);
        switch (msg.Type)
        {
            case MessageType.Error:
                //
                GLib.GException err;
                string debug;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bus_Message: Error received: " + msg.ToString());
                break;
            case MessageType.StreamStatus:
                Gst.StreamStatusType status;
                Element theOwner;
                msg.ParseStreamStatus(out status, out theOwner);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bus_Message: Case SteamingStatus: status is: " + status + " ; Owner is: " + theOwner.Name);
                break;
            case MessageType.StateChanged:
                State oldState, newState, pendingState;
                msg.ParseStateChanged(out oldState, out newState, out pendingState);
                if (newState == State.Paused)
                    args.RetVal = false;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bus_Message: Pipeline state changed from {0} to {1}: ; Pending: {2}", Element.StateGetName(oldState), Element.StateGetName(newState), Element.StateGetName(pendingState));
                break;
            case MessageType.Element:
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bus_Message: Element message: {0}", args.Message.ToString());
                break;
            default:
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bus_Message: HandleMessage received msg of type: {0}", msg.Type);
                break;
        }
        args.RetVal = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the main reason is that the elements don't know if they can be connected unless they are actually playing. Simply because the format that is being received is not known. Perhaps try some decodebin or playbin elements in this case? I guess they exist for this particuliar reason. You should also receive your sync/prepare message for the renderer as well. You also some some control over the videosinks being used (in case you use playbin).

Comment: Hi Florian, I did wonder wether I was approaching it in the correct way, my end goal is to perform analysis on the image using emgu/opencv so I might skip ahead and head towards using appsink to get at the data. I know I can display the frames in WPF using emgu as I already have done some work from USB cams. The latency issue is why I headed to gstreamer and Ive seen some good results. I might pursue this for a few mor edays as it would be nice to answer my own question for closure :) Thanks.

Comment: If you are interesting in appsink you may want to try `playbin` and set the `uri` property with your RTSP uri and the `video-sink` property with a previously instantiated `appsink`.

Comment: Hi Florian, Yes I have started experimenting with appsink just now. I managed to get the first stage working (see my answer below). I will be doing some further work to get access to individual frames/samples so I can do the overlay/recording/analysis work I want to do next. Thanks for your tips!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok everyone I managed to get past the issues I was having.

The first problem (pad added not being called consistantly) seemed to be fixed by building for x64 instead of any cpu or x86. I suspect my installation of the gstreamer libs didnt finish correctly.

The second issue (NOFORMAT when linking new pad) was a bit more work. In the end I followed Florian's suggestion and looked at using uridecodebin for the source and just linked the new pad directly to the autovideosink....no elements inbetween.

I now get a consistent new pad added and the prepare window handle bus sync message is sent every time. I have four separate IP streams now going to four winforms panels with good latency (still to test glass to glass).

To ensure the latency was (sort of) tuned I had to delve into the source-setup signal of uridecodebin and assuming the source is of type rtspsrc then set the "latency" property of it. The code below doesnt verify the source type so YMMV and you may get an exception here.

Please see source code for the class below which works for me (compiled for x64).

Hope this is of some help to anyone out there.

Now to move onto appsink!! :)

```
/// <summary>
/// class to create a gstreamer pipeline based on an rtsp stream at the provided URL
/// </summary>
class gstPipeline2
{
    // elements for the pipeline
    private Element uriDecodeBin, videoSink;
    private System.Threading.Thread mainGLibThread;
    private GLib.MainLoop mainLoop;

    // the window handle (passed in)
    private IntPtr windowHandle;
    // our pipeline
    private Pipeline currentPipeline = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new gstreamer pipeline rendering the stream at URL into the provided window handle 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="WindowHandle">The handle of the window to render to </param>
    /// <param name="Url">The url of the video stream</param>
    public gstPipeline2(string Url, IntPtr WindowHandle)
    {
        windowHandle = WindowHandle;    // get the handle and save it locally

        // initialise the gstreamer library and associated threads (for diagnostics)
        Gst.Application.Init();

        mainLoop = new GLib.MainLoop();
        mainGLibThread = new System.Threading.Thread(mainLoop.Run);
        mainGLibThread.Start();

        // create each element now for the pipeline
        uriDecodeBin = ElementFactory.Make("uridecodebin", "uriDecodeBin0");  // create an uridecodebin (which handles most of the work for us!!)
        uriDecodeBin["uri"] = Url;   // and set its location (the source of the data)
        videoSink = ElementFactory.Make("autovideosink", "sink0");  // and finally the sink to render the video (redirected to the required window handle below in Bus_SyncMessage() ) 

        // create our pipeline which links all the elements together into a valid data flow
        currentPipeline = new Pipeline("pipeline");
        currentPipeline.Add(uriDecodeBin, videoSink); // add the required elements into it

        uriDecodeBin.PadAdded += uriDecodeBin_PadAdded; // subscribe to the PadAdded event so we can link new pads (sources of data?) to the depayloader when they arrive
        uriDecodeBin.Connect("source-setup", SourceSetup);  // subscribe to the "source-setup" signal, not quite done in the usual C# eventing way but treat it as essentially the same

        // subscribe to the messaging system of the bus and pipeline so we can monitor status as we go
        Bus bus = currentPipeline.Bus;
        bus.AddSignalWatch();
        bus.Message += Bus_Message;

        bus.EnableSyncMessageEmission();
        bus.SyncMessage += Bus_SyncMessage;

        // finally set the state of the pipeline running so we can get data
        var setStateReturn = currentPipeline.SetState(State.Null);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SetStateNULL returned: " + setStateReturn.ToString());
        setStateReturn = currentPipeline.SetState(State.Ready);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SetStateReady returned: " + setStateReturn.ToString());
        setStateReturn = currentPipeline.SetState(State.Playing);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SetStatePlaying returned: " + setStateReturn.ToString());
    }

    private void uriDecodeBin_PadAdded(object o, PadAddedArgs args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("uriDecodeBin_PadAdded: called with new pad named: " + args.NewPad.Name);

        // a pad has been added to the source so we need to link it to the rest of the pipeline to ultimately display it onscreen
        Pad sinkPad = videoSink.GetStaticPad("sink");   // get the pad for the one we have recieved  so we can link to the depayloader element
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("uriDecodeBin_PadAdded: queue pad returned: " + sinkPad.Name);

        PadLinkReturn ret = args.NewPad.Link(sinkPad);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("uriDecodeBin_PadAdded: link attempt returned: " + ret.ToString());
    }

    void SourceSetup(object sender, GLib.SignalArgs args)
    {
        // we need to delve into the source portion of the uridecodebin to modify the "latency" property, need to add some validation here to ensure this is an rtspsrc
        var source = (Element)args.Args[0];
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SourceSetup: source is named: " + source.Name + ", and is of type: " + source.NativeType.ToString());
        source["latency"] = 0;  // this COULD throw an exception if the source is not rtspsrc or similar with a "latency" property
    }

    public void killProcess()
    {
        mainLoop.Quit();
    }

    private void Bus_SyncMessage(object o, SyncMessageArgs args)
    {
        if (Gst.Video.Global.IsVideoOverlayPrepareWindowHandleMessage(args.Message))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bus_SyncMessage: Message prepare window handle received by: " + args.Message.Src.Name + " " + args.Message.Src.GetType().ToString());

            if (args.Message.Src != null)
            {
                // these checks were in the testvideosrc example and failed, args.Message.Src is always Gst.Element???
                if (args.Message.Src is Gst.Video.VideoSink)
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bus_SyncMessage: source is VideoSink");
                else
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bus_SyncMessage: source is NOT VideoSink");

                if (args.Message.Src is Gst.Bin)
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bus_SyncMessage: source is Bin");
                else
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bus_SyncMessage: source is NOT Bin");

                try
                {
                    args.Message.Src["force-aspect-ratio"] = true;
                }
                catch (PropertyNotFoundException) { }

                try
                {
                    Gst.Video.VideoOverlayAdapter adapter = new VideoOverlayAdapter(args.Message.Src.Handle);
                    adapter.WindowHandle = windowHandle;
                    adapter.HandleEvents(true);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bus_SyncMessage: Handle passed to adapter: " + windowHandle.ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bus_SyncMessage: Exception Thrown (overlay stage): " + ex.Message); }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string info;
            IntPtr prt;
            args.Message.ParseInfo(out prt, out info);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bus_SyncMessage: " + args.Message.Type.ToString() + " - " + info);
        }
    }

    private void Bus_Message(object o, MessageArgs args)
    {
        var msg = args.Message;
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("HandleMessage received msg of type: {0}", msg.Type);
        switch (msg.Type)
        {
            case MessageType.Error:
                //
                GLib.GException err;
                string debug;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bus_Message: Error received: " + msg.ToString());
                break;
            case MessageType.StreamStatus:
                Gst.StreamStatusType status;
                Element theOwner;
                msg.ParseStreamStatus(out status, out theOwner);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bus_Message: Case SteamingStatus: status is: " + status + " ; Owner is: " + theOwner.Name);
                break;
            case MessageType.StateChanged:
                State oldState, newState, pendingState;
                msg.ParseStateChanged(out oldState, out newState, out pendingState);
                if (newState == State.Paused)
                    args.RetVal = false;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bus_Message: Pipeline state changed from {0} to {1}: ; Pending: {2}", Element.StateGetName(oldState), Element.StateGetName(newState), Element.StateGetName(pendingState));
                break;
            case MessageType.Element:
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bus_Message: Element message: {0}", args.Message.ToString());
                break;
            default:
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bus_Message: HandleMessage received msg of type: {0}", msg.Type);
                break;
        }
        args.RetVal = true;
    }
}
```