# GStreamer Sharp with custom stream does not shown

Tags: c#, winforms, video-streaming, gstreamer, gstreamer-sharp

actually I have almoust the same quastion which was already mentionen in the attached task:
[Display gstreamer-sharp video stream in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916330/display-gstreamer-sharp-video-stream-in-winforms)

The purposed implementation was tested and it works fine with "videotestsrc" and with "bunny" video from network.

My problem is:

I would like to show the custom stream on windows GUI application (stream is generated by RPi)

The RPi generates a stream in a local network with the following command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v libcamerasrc ! video/x-raw, width=640, height=480, framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.219  port=5000
```

and it can be **successfully** read on windows PC with the corresponding command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc uri=127.0.0.1 port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, media=video, clock-rate=90000, payload=96 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

The code I'm using is given below:

**Streamer.cs** ->

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Thread = System.Threading.Thread;
using Gst;
using GLib;
using Gst.Video;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Gst.App;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;
using static System.Net.WebRequestMethods;
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;

namespace VideoDoorTesting
{
    public class VideoPipe
    {
        public Gst.Pipeline pipeline;         /* The running pipeline */
        public  Gst.Element source;
        public  Gst.Element capsfilter;
        public  Gst.Element convert;
        public  Gst.Element codec;
        public  Gst.Element encoder;
        public  Gst.Element sink;
        public  Gst.Video.VideoSink videoSink;
        public  Gst.State state;               /* Current pipeline state */
        public Gst.State target_state;        /* Desired pipeline state, to be set once buffering is complete */
    }

    public class UsedData
    {

        public MainLoop mainLoop;
        public VideoPipe videoPipe;
        public Thread mainGlibThread;
        public VideoOverlayAdapter adapter;
        public uint refreshUiHandle;
        public IntPtr nativeWindow;
    }
    class Streamer
    {
        public delegate void OnDrawReceivedEventHandler(Element videoSink, GLib.SignalArgs args);
        public OnDrawReceivedEventHandler OnDrawSignalReceived;
        private bool isInitialised = false;
        private UsedData userData;
        
        #region stream control functions
        public bool startVideoStream()
        {
            var ret = userData.videoPipe.pipeline.SetState(State.Playing);
            if (ret == StateChangeReturn.Failure)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        public bool stopVideoStream()
        {
            var ret = userData.videoPipe.pipeline.SetState(State.Ready);
            if (ret == StateChangeReturn.Failure)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        #endregion
        
        public void Close()
        {
            try
            {
                userData.videoPipe.pipeline.SetState(State.Ready);
                userData.videoPipe.pipeline.SetState(State.Null);
                userData.mainLoop.Quit();
                
                userData.videoPipe.source.Unlink(userData.videoPipe.capsfilter);
                userData.videoPipe.capsfilter.Unlink(userData.videoPipe.codec);
                userData.videoPipe.codec.Unlink(userData.videoPipe.encoder);
                userData.videoPipe.encoder.Unlink(userData.videoPipe.convert);
                userData.videoPipe.convert.Unlink(userData.videoPipe.sink);

                userData.videoPipe.pipeline.Remove(userData.videoPipe.source,
                userData.videoPipe.capsfilter,
                userData.videoPipe.codec,
                userData.videoPipe.encoder,
                userData.videoPipe.convert,
                userData.videoPipe.sink);
                
                userData.videoPipe.pipeline.Dispose();
                userData.videoPipe.capsfilter.Dispose();
                userData.videoPipe.codec.Dispose();
                userData.videoPipe.convert.Dispose();
                userData.videoPipe.encoder.Dispose();


            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }

        }

        public Streamer(IntPtr videoPanel)
        {
            
            userData = new UsedData();
            userData.nativeWindow = videoPanel;
            userData.videoPipe = new VideoPipe();
            
            InitGst(userData);
            initVideoPipe(userData);    
            userData.videoPipe.pipeline.Bus.EnableSyncMessageEmission();
            userData.videoPipe.pipeline.Bus.AddSignalWatch();
            userData.videoPipe.pipeline.Bus.Message += OnBusMessage;

            userData.videoPipe.pipeline.Bus.SyncMessage += OnBusSyncMessage;
            userData.videoPipe.pipeline.AutoFlushBus = true;

        }

        private void OnBusMessage(object o, MessageArgs margs)
        {
            try
            {
                Gst.Message message = margs.Message;
                switch (message.Type)
                {
                    case MessageType.Eos:
                        var ret = userData.videoPipe.pipeline.SetState(Gst.State.Ready);

                        if (ret == StateChangeReturn.Async)
                            ret = userData.videoPipe.pipeline.GetState(out var state, out var pending, Gst.Constants.SECOND * 10L);

                        if (ret == StateChangeReturn.Success)
                        {
                            ret = userData.videoPipe.pipeline.SetState(Gst.State.Playing);
                            if (ret == StateChangeReturn.Async)
                                ret = userData.videoPipe.pipeline.GetState(out var state, out var pending, Gst.Constants.SECOND * 10L);
                        }
                        break;
                    case MessageType.Error:
                        message.ParseError(out GException err, out string debug);
                        if (debug == null)
                        {
                            debug = "none";
                        }
                        if (err.Code == 3)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("?");
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine(message.Type.ToString());
                        break;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }

        private void OnBusSyncMessage(object o, SyncMessageArgs sargs)
        {
            Gst.Message msg = sargs.Message;

            if (!Gst.Video.Global.IsVideoOverlayPrepareWindowHandleMessage(msg))
            {
                
                msg.Dispose();
                return;
            }

            Element src = msg.Src as Element;

            if (src == null)
            {
                msg.Dispose();
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                src["force-aspect-ratio"] = true;
            }
            catch (PropertyNotFoundException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message, ex);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(msg.Type.ToString());
            Element overlay = ((Gst.Bin)userData.videoPipe.pipeline)?.GetByInterface(VideoOverlayAdapter.GType);

            userData.adapter = new VideoOverlayAdapter(overlay.Handle);
            userData.adapter.WindowHandle = userData.nativeWindow;
            userData.adapter.HandleEvents(true);
            
            msg?.Dispose();
            overlay?.Dispose();
            src?.Dispose();
        }
        
        private void VideoSink_OnBeginDraw(object o, GLib.SignalArgs args)
        {
             OnDrawSignalReceived?.Invoke((Element)o, args);
        }
        
        #region Init functions
        protected void InitGst(UsedData userData)
        {
            Gst.Application.Init();
            GtkSharp.GstreamerSharp.ObjectManager.Initialize();
            userData.mainLoop = new MainLoop();
            userData.mainGlibThread = new Thread(userData.mainLoop.Run);
            userData.mainGlibThread.Start();
        }

        protected bool initVideoPipe(UsedData userData)
        {
            try
            {
                userData.videoPipe.pipeline = new Pipeline("pipeline");
                userData.videoPipe.source = ElementFactory.Make("udpsrc", "source");
                userData.videoPipe.source["uri"] = "127.0.0.1";
                userData.videoPipe.source["port"] = 5000;

                userData.videoPipe.capsfilter = ElementFactory.Make("capsfilter", "capsfilter");
                var caps = Gst.Global.CapsFromString("application/x-rtp, media=video, clock-rate=90000, payload=96 ");
                userData.videoPipe.capsfilter["caps"] = caps;

                userData.videoPipe.codec = ElementFactory.Make("rtpjpegdepay", "codec");
                userData.videoPipe.encoder = ElementFactory.Make("jpegdec", "encoder");
                userData.videoPipe.convert = ElementFactory.Make("videoconvert", "converter");// noise-shaping=4");
                
                userData.videoPipe.sink = ElementFactory.Make("autovideosink", "sink");// host=239.0.0.1 auto-multicast=true port=5001");

                //userData.videoPipe.videoSink = (Gst.Video.VideoSink)Gst.ElementFactory.Make("glimagesink", "glimagesink");

                //userData.videoPipe.videoSink = (Gst.Video.VideoSink)Gst.ElementFactory.Make("d3dvideosink", "d3dvideosink");

                //userData.videoPipe.videoSink = (Gst.Video.VideoSink)Gst.ElementFactory.Make("dshowvideosink", "dshowvideosink");

                userData.videoPipe.videoSink = (Gst.Video.VideoSink)Gst.ElementFactory.Make("directdrawsink", "directdrawsink");


                userData.videoPipe.pipeline.Add(userData.videoPipe.source,
                                                userData.videoPipe.capsfilter,
                                                userData.videoPipe.codec,
                                                userData.videoPipe.encoder,
                                                userData.videoPipe.convert,
                                                userData.videoPipe.sink,
                                                userData.videoPipe.videoSink);

                userData.videoPipe.source.Link(userData.videoPipe.capsfilter);
                userData.videoPipe.capsfilter.Link(userData.videoPipe.codec);
                userData.videoPipe.codec.Link(userData.videoPipe.encoder);
                userData.videoPipe.encoder.Link(userData.videoPipe.convert);
                userData.videoPipe.source.Link(userData.videoPipe.convert);
                userData.videoPipe.convert.Link(userData.videoPipe.sink);
                userData.videoPipe.sink.Link(userData.videoPipe.videoSink);

                userData.videoPipe.pipeline.SetState(State.Null);
                userData.videoPipe.pipeline.SetState(State.Ready);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message, ex);
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        #endregion

        internal void Cleanup()
        {
            try
            {
                userData.adapter?.HandleEvents(false);
                userData.videoPipe.sink?.Disconnect("begin-draw", VideoSink_OnBeginDraw);

                if (userData.videoPipe.pipeline != null)
                {
                    userData.videoPipe.pipeline.Bus.Message -= OnBusMessage;
                    userData.videoPipe.pipeline.Bus.SyncMessage -= OnBusSyncMessage;
                }


                userData.videoPipe.pipeline?.SetState(State.Null);
                userData.videoPipe.pipeline?.Dispose();
                userData.mainLoop?.Quit();

                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Stremaer is started as
...
**streamer = new Streamer(videoPanel.Handle);**
...
**streamer.startVideoStream();**

But the stream does not appers in a windows. Additional: the memory is allocation expands (form 27 to approx. 100 MB) after start and **OnBusSyncMessage(...)** event also comes, but with "warning".

Could some one point on my mistake?
Thank in advance
D.Krush